# Multiplying by a decimal wont give me a decimal answer to feed back into my variable

Tags: c++, if-statement, clion

Currently using Clion to work on a homework question.  I believe i am using my if-statements correctly, as-well as the double and char but it doesn't seem to be giving me the outcome i seek.  The question asks:

- Buy one get one half off promotion: the lower price item is half price.
- If the customer is club card member, additional 10% off.
- Tax is added.

I have tried to move brackets around.  I have declared the .90 to a set variable and tried multiplying that but still always gives me the same answer.  I think it has something to do with my if-statemets.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

double price1, price2, taxRate, fullSubtotal;

char clubCard;

double basePrice, cardPrice, finalPrice;


    // ...

    cout<<"Enter price of first item: ";
    cin>>price1;
    cout<<"Enter price of second item: ";
    cin>>price2;

    cout<<"Does customer have a club card? (Y/N): ";
    cin>>clubCard;

    cout<<"Enter tax rate, e.g. 5.5 for 5.5% tax: ";
    cin>>taxRate;

    fullSubtotal = price1 + price2;
    taxRate /= 100;
    taxRate += 1;

    if (price1 > price2) {
        price2 /= 2.00;
        basePrice = price1 + price2;
        if (clubCard == 'y' || clubCard == 'Y') {
            cardPrice = basePrice * .90;
           finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
        }
        else (clubCard == 'n' || clubCard == 'N'); {
            cardPrice = basePrice;
            finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
        }
    }
    else {
        price1 /= 2.00;
        basePrice = price1 + price2;
        if ((clubCard == 'y') || (clubCard == 'Y')) {
            cardPrice = basePrice * .90;
            finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
        }
        else ((clubCard == 'n') || (clubCard == 'N')); {
            cardPrice = basePrice;
            finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Base price: "<<fullSubtotal<<endl;
    cout<<"Price after discounts: "<<cardPrice<<endl;
    cout<<"Total price: "<<finalPrice<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Each time i enter the values for each price( 10 and 20), it gives me the correct fullSubtotal, but when i seek the corresponding cardPrice for that route (if-statement), it gives me 25.  With a total price (including tax) to be 27.0625.   I was expecting the output to be, cardPrice: 22.5 with finalPrice: 24.35625

Comment: Post the complete program. We can't see your variable declarations etc. Also, your `else` lines contains conditions so they should be `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is at the inner else clause.

An else-clause has no condition, so the `(clubCard == 'n' || clubCard == 'N');` is useless, but still correct c++. It evaluates to a bool that is then discarded. The problem is, that the the block after this is always executed, because it has no condition anymore.

Either use `else if` and drop the semicolon or just drop the whole condition and the semicolon:

```
...
if (clubCard == 'y' || clubCard == 'Y') {
    cardPrice = basePrice * .90;
   finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
}
else {
    cardPrice = basePrice;
    finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `else` sections:

```
    if(clubCard == 'y' || clubCard == 'Y') {
        cardPrice = basePrice * .90;
        finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
    } else
        (clubCard == 'n' || clubCard == 'N');
    {
        cardPrice = basePrice;
        finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
    }
```

The condition you tried to add for the `else` becomes a statement and the code in the {} block after overwrites the values you previously set. Fix:

```
    if(clubCard == 'y' || clubCard == 'Y') {
        cardPrice = basePrice * .90;
        finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
    } else if(clubCard == 'n' || clubCard == 'N') {
        cardPrice = basePrice;
        finalPrice = taxRate * cardPrice;
    }
```